# Nice-looking URLs for assets

Tags: assets, url

Is there a way to get "vanity URLs" for my assets? Something like:

www.example.com/download/asset.pdf

rather than:

www.example.com/several/subfolders/for/organisation/purposes/asset.pdf

I know that dumping all assets into a /download folder will work but this is far from an ideal solution. Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps using redirects and Regex in your .htaccess? There's a Craft plugin that would help with this.
https://github.com/rkingon/Craft-Plugin--Redirect-Manager/

You could use something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /download/(.*) /several/subfolders/for/organisation/purposes/$1
```

You would need to refine this for matching several different subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for this. I asked the question and then kinda forgot about it.